# How do I obtain the subset of a unique-ptrs in a vector, which satisfy a predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11, iteration, unique-ptr, predicate

I have a vector of `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` objects. I want to get a collection of all vector items that match some condition. 
I see the std functions but they all seem to test for a predicate (and return bool) or return a single element.

Is there a built-in mechanism to get a collection that's a subset of a vector? If not, is there a way to construct an iterator that tests items against an arbitrary predicate (to identify ones that meet my condition) and a mechanism to return all items that meet that predicate?

Comment: Does `std::copy_if` meet your requirements?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: What do you want the type of the returned subset to be? And is the original vector to be changed or not? You really need to specify your problem more exactly.

Comment: I want the subset to also be a vector of Foo pointers. I don't want the original vector impacted. I do want to edit the items in the subset vector and have those edits reflects in the original vector. I'm assuming using pointers should ensure that's the case.

Comment: Richard - I think I'm going to remove the unique_ptr requirement and use copy_if.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be warned, since you've got a vector of unique_ptr, those elements can only be **moved** around, i.e. once you have got the subset, the original vector will not be the same anymore.

---

The least destructive method is to use [`std::stable_partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) to divide the vector into two groups, while keeping everything in the same vector:

```
auto sep = std::stable_partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& foo) {
    return foo->is_good();
});
// the part `vec.begin() .. sep` contains all "good" foos.
// the part `sep .. vec.end()` contains all "bad" foos.
```

If order is not important, [use `std::partition` instead](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition). The usage is the same.

If you want to split the bad foos into another vector, you could use [`std::copy_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) + [`std::make_move_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) to move the objects out. Note that this will leave holes everywhere. Use `std::remove` to clean them up.

```
decltype(vec) bad_vec;
std::copy_if(std::make_move_iterator(vec.begin()),
             std::make_move_iterator(vec.end()),
             std::back_inserter(bad_vec),
             [](const auto& p) { return !p->is_good(); });
auto new_end = std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), nullptr);
vec.erase(new_end, vec.end());
```

If you no longer care about the "bad" objects, use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const auto& foo) {
    return !foo->is_good();
});
vec.erase(new_end, vec.end());
// now `vec` only contains "good" foos.
```

---

If you just want to get the raw pointers, instead of the unique_ptr itself, you could use `std::transform` to fill up a `vector<Foo*>` and then `remove_if` to filter it... But at this point it is probably just easier to write the for loop.

```
std::vector<int*> good_vec;
for (const auto& foo : vec) {
    if (foo->is_good()) {
        good_vec.push_back(foo.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: A vector of `std::reference_wrapper`s or indexes into the original vector are other non-destructive options.

Answer (score 2):

Since your vector holds `unique_ptr`'s (which we don't make copies of) - I'd recommend the second option you inquired about: An iterator which only iterates those elements matching your predicate. This is exactly [`boost::filter_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html).

Sort-of-an example:

```
bool points_to_positive(int* ptr) { 
    return ptr != nullptr and *ptr > 0; 
}

// ...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> vec;

// ...

auto iterator = boost::make_filter_iterator(
    &points_to_positive, std::begin(vec), std::end(vec)
);
```

if, however, you plan on making that iteration multiple times, and do not want to trade time for space, you would probably be better served by just copying out the actual pointers like in @kennytm's last suggested option.

Comment: Is there a STL version of filter_iterator if I remove the unique_ptr requirement?

Comment: @Craig: Not if my memory serves me correctly, the standard library is kind of lacking in iterator-related facilities. ... but it's not very difficult to make your own. It's quite a bit of boiler-plate, but other than that - same as the usual iterator, except that your `operator++`,  `operator+` etc. implementations advance while counting the elements satisfying the predicate.

Answer (score 1):

What you asked for is `std::copy_if` from `<algorithm>`.  For `unique_ptr` elements, which cannot be copied, this is not what you want.  Sample code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <experimental/array>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::size_t;

bool is_even( const int n )
{
  // True iff n is even.
  return n % 2 == 0;
}

std::ostream& operator<< ( std::ostream& os, const std::vector<int>& container )
{
  // Boilerplate instrumentation.
  for ( const int& x : container )
    os << x << ' ';

  return os;
}

int main(void)
{
  // Our input array, raw:
  constexpr int digits[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
  // The number of input elements:
  constexpr size_t ndigits = std::extent<decltype(digits)>();
  // Container wrapping our input array:
  constexpr std::array<int, ndigits > numbers =
    std::experimental::to_array(digits);
  std::vector<int> even_numbers;

  even_numbers.reserve(ndigits); // Upper bound on output size.
  std::copy_if( numbers.cbegin(),
                numbers.cend(),
                std::back_inserter(even_numbers),
                is_even );
  even_numbers.shrink_to_fit();

  // Correct output is "2 4 6 8 "
  cout << even_numbers << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**However,** your array contains `unique_ptr` objects, which can’t be copied. Several answers have other good suggestions to get equivalent results.  If you want to copy the references meeting the requirements to a different collection, though, you could also change `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` or `weak_ptr`, which can be copied.

Comment: Are you sure you want to suggest that OP make copies of `unique_ptr`s?

Comment: Added a line at the bottom.  Several other answers give good alternatives! Those answers are great and I see no need to repeat them.  I just gave some demo code for the question the OP asked.

Comment: Will your suggestion work, though, seeing how `unique_ptr`s can't be copied? (I'm trying to save you downvotes here...)

Comment: I added a stronger warning at the bottom that this is what the OP asked for, not what he or she wants.

Comment: That said, changing `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` or some other copyable type is just as valid a modification of the question as using some other algorithm that doesn’t make copies.